# jQuery: Issue with if

Tags: jquery

```
$("#test > div > div.row-fluid > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(3)").after("<td><i class='fa fa-plus-square-o'></i></td>");

$("#test > div > div.row-fluid > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(4)").click(function()
{
    if ($("#test > div > div.row-fluid > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(4) > i").hasClass("fa fa-plus-square-o")){
        $(this).replaceWith("<td><i class='fa fa-minus-square-o'></i></td>");
    }
    if ($("#test > div > div.row-fluid > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(4) > i").hasClass("fa fa-minus-square-o")){
        $(this).replaceWith("<td><i class='fa fa-plus-square-o'></i></td>");
    }
});
```

This is the code I have. First `if` works, but after it has changed, but second `if` doesn't work if I want to change it back.

Thanks!

Comment: Just assuming this is an X-Y problem, if you're trying to toggle the class on that specific element, there are much better ways.

Comment: You are trying to "flip it", and then immediately flip it back?

Comment: @mcsilvio, not immediately, but when I want to.

Comment: Is there a particular reason your selector is so long? Something like this is (probably) perfectly adequate: `#test .row-fluid td:nth-child(4)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to change the class on the `i`, try `toggle`:-

```
$("#test > div > div.row-fluid > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(4)").click(function()
{
    $('i', this).toggleClass('fa-plus-square-o fa-minus-square-o');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(document).on("click","#test > div > div.row-fluid > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(4) > i",function()
{
    $(this).toggleClass("fa-minus-square-o fa-plus-square-o");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use document statement on events, after changing content it cannot determine new classes this way.

But a better way to achieve it is by doing this:

```
if($('#test etc..').hasClass('fa-minus-square-o')){
    $(this).attr('class', 'fa fa-plus-square-o');
    // or toggleClass
}
```